# Connecting frontend (react) to backend (node) using codesandbox

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql, codesandbox

I am using react, graphql and node. Currently, my react codes are on codesandbox, whilst my server codes are on my local computer. How do i link up my frontend with my backend in this case? Do i need to deploy my server codes onto heroku or digital ocean before i can link them? I like to be able to test them first before deploying my codes

I am also thinking of migrating my backend codes to codesandbox. In this case, am i still able to link my frontend and backend codes in order to test them out before deploying to the hosting provider servers?

Thanks

Comment: Should be able to make requests from your front end to localhost no? Keep in mind will need to enable cors middleware due to different origins

Comment: Are you using `apollo` in your local GraphQL server?

Answer (score 0):

Charlie is correct. I actually build my react frontend on codesandbox and connected to my node graphql backend on codesandbox too. Both must be running for that to work. Must enable cors too for both to connect. As im using apollo server 2, can pass a cors: true to the apollo server constructor.

Comment: Thanks folks for giving me ideas to solve the issue. Hope my answer helps ya all too :)